# How do i change multiple elements which should have the same value with javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to replace the {title} within the following div

```
<a href="{pagelink}" title="{title}" class="link">
                            <img data-imgurl="{imgsrc}" class="img-responsive div-details-logo-image" alt="{title}" src="{imgsrc}">
                            <div class="div-details-image">
                                <h2 class="div-details-title">{title}</h2>

                                <div class="label-container">
                                    <span class="label-type" data-type="{type}">{type}</span>
                                </div>
                                <span class="div-details-address">{Address}</span>
                                <span class="openhours"> {opentimes}</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
```

For this i have come up with the follow js function, which works if i only target one class instance

```
function updateDivDetails(attributes) {
                var x = document.getElementById("itemDetails");
                x.querySelector(".div-details-address").innerHTML = attributes.address;
                x.querySelector(".div-details-title").innerHTML = attributes.title;
                etc
            }
```

The use of class selector to change the {title} seems not the way to do it.

Any tips how to change {title} from the js function??

Comment: How do you call/invoke the function?

Comment: @Mamun at the moment is part of a marker on click event `markers.on('click', function (e) { ....updateDivDetails(attributes);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.replace` instead

Get the parent element and change all occurrences

```js
const o = {
  title: "Title",
  text: "Lorem ipsum"
}

let container = document.getElementById('container');
let t = container.innerHTML;

container.innerHTML = t
  .replace(/{title}/g, o.title)
  .replace(/{text}/g, o.text);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h3>{title}</h3>
  <p>{title}: {text}</p>
</div>
```

---

### Update

You can save the original html into an variable, like that you can change the content multiple times with different object data.

```js
const foo = {
  title: "Title",
  text: "Lorem ipsum"
}
const bar = {
  title: "Title 2",
  text: "Ipsum lorem"
}
let container = document.getElementById('container');
let template = container.innerHTML;


function changeText(obj) {
  container.innerHTML = template
    .replace(/{title}/g, obj.title)
    .replace(/{text}/g, obj.text);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h3>{title}</h3>
  <p>{title}: {text}</p>
</div>


<button onclick="changeText(foo)">First</button>
<button onclick="changeText(bar)">Second</button>
```

Comment: Tx, this seem to work only once.....after clicking the first marker every other marker has the same content

Comment: you first answer works ok. I had to place the 'let' outside my function.  I need to readup as i have never used let before. tx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually updating individual element, you can use a generic logic and update it.

You can create a list of possible elements selectors and update it based on common format.

```js
function updateDivDetails(attributes) {
  var x = document.getElementById("itemDetails");
  const selector = ".div-details-address, .div-details-title";
  Array.from(x.querySelectorAll(selector)).forEach((el) => {
    const key = el.innerText.replace(/[{}]/g, '').trim().toLowerCase();
    el.innerText = attributes[key]
  })
}

const dummyData = {
  title: 'Dummy Title',
  address: 'Dummy Address'
}
updateDivDetails(dummyData)
```

```html
<a href="{pagelink}" title="{title}" class="link" id="itemDetails">
  <img data-imgurl="{imgsrc}" class="img-responsive div-details-logo-image" alt="{title}" src="{imgsrc}">
  <div class="div-details-image">
    <h2 class="div-details-title">{title}</h2>

    <div class="label-container">
      <span class="label-type" data-type="{type}">{type}</span>
    </div>
    <span class="div-details-address">{Address}</span>
    <span class="openhours"> {opentimes}</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Above solution might work but its not scalable. If you have option to update markup, you should use `data-` attribute and based on than fetch new value and set it.

For demonstration purpose, I have added `data-attr="KeyName"` and fetched based on that

```js
function updateDivDetails(attributes) {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#itemDetails [data-attr]")).forEach((el) => {
    el.innerText = attributes[ el.getAttribute('data-attr') ];
  })
}

const dummyData = {
  title: 'Dummy Title',
  address: 'Dummy Address'
}
updateDivDetails(dummyData)
```

```html
<a href="{pagelink}" title="{title}" class="link" id="itemDetails">
  <img data-imgurl="{imgsrc}" class="img-responsive div-details-logo-image" alt="{title}" src="{imgsrc}">
  <div class="div-details-image">
    <h2 class="div-details-title" data-attr="title">{title}</h2>

    <div class="label-container">
      <span class="label-type" data-type="{type}">{type}</span>
    </div>
    <span class="div-details-address" data-attr="address">{Address}</span>
    <span class="openhours"> {opentimes}</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

---

Also, note that replacing `innerHtml` can have side effect. Better to set `innerText` instead

Comment: *Also, note that replacing innerHtml can have side effect. Better to set innerText instead*. I think it's false, because he use `{title}` into html too. e.g. `<a href="{pagelink}" title="{title}" class="link">`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, so what is the issue?

You do know that you can only have **one element per page with any given `id` value**?

```js
function updateDivDetails(attributes) {
  var x = document.getElementById("itemDetails");
  x.querySelector(".div-details-address").innerHTML = attributes.address;
  x.querySelector(".div-details-title").innerHTML = attributes.title;
}

const y = {
  address: 'address inserted',
  title: 'title inserted'
};

updateDivDetails(y);
```

```html
<div id="itemDetails">
  <a href="{pagelink}" title="{title}" class="link">
    <img data-imgurl="{imgsrc}" class="img-responsive div-details-logo-image" alt="{title}" src="{imgsrc}">
    <div class="div-details-image">
      <h2 class="div-details-title">{title}</h2>

      <div class="label-container">
        <span class="label-type" data-type="{type}">{type}</span>
      </div>
      <span class="div-details-address">{Address}</span>
      <span class="openhours"> {opentimes}</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you made any change in code? Apart from adding object `y` and make it complete snippet

Comment: I have only added a wrapping div with `id="itemDetails"` because your code didn't have that. Other than that I have only added an example object that serves as an argument for `updateDivDetails`.

Comment: per question (*which works if i only target*), OP's code works and the missing `id` must be in some higher element. Also, the data must also be available. So your answer should have been a comment

Comment: @connexo yes i realised it. I was first changing/updating the address part by selecting the class, but when I wanted to change the {title}  instances i notice i couldn't use class selector as some of the {title} instance is a attribute. So something like .replace would be sufficient like R3tep suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that you have is that you do not select the element the right way.

Here are few lines to do it:

```js
let h2Element = document.querySelector('.div-details-title');
h2Element.textContent = "New Title";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="{pagelink}" title="{title}" class="link">
    <img data-imgurl="{imgsrc}" class="img-responsive div-details-logo-image" alt="{title}" src="{imgsrc}">
    <div class="div-details-image">
        <h2 class="div-details-title">{title}</h2>

        <div class="label-container">
            <span class="label-type" data-type="{type}">{type}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="div-details-address">{Address}</span>
        <span class="openhours"> {opentimes}</span>
    </div>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```